# ASP.NET Login Control display textboxes with different sizes, depending on the Browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm using the Login control, which produces 2 textboxes, one for **login** and the other for the **password**. In CHROME, the both controls have the same length. In IE, the password control looks longer that the login one. When I set the size of the login to 26, and that of the password to 25 (using javascript). Both controls look the same in IE, but one look different in CHROME. In each case, I'm getting a different look in IE or CHROME.

CHROME

[image]

IE.

[image]

Is there a way I can use the Login Control with a template? so that I can apply CSS to fix this problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877780/how-do-i-style-the-asp-net-membership-control-with-css. I think that should help

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that it's possible to access the elements to be produced by the Login control.